# Programmatically installing and uninstalling exe files?

Tags: c#, installation, exe, uninstallation

I have a program that at the moment which can handle the installing and uninstalling of .msi files without a problem using msiexec.exe.

However I want to know a way to do the same but with .exe installers? I'm not sure of any existing methods to do this, and understand that I cannot use the msiexec.exe approach to do this?

Thanks

Comment: _"but with .exe installers"_ - what do you mean?

Comment: @MickyDuncan This may be my misunderstanding. A .exe file which after running opens up an installation dialogue requiring the user to select installation properties. Is it possible to quietly install these without any user interaction?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Sounds like you want _silent installers_?

Comment: @MickyDuncan I found my answer thanks. It was a matter of starting a process with the arguments as /SILENT or /VERYSILENT, as the installer was using an Inno Setup installer.